# How to benchmark executing in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, benchmarking

I want to executing benckmark test and I follow the [Elasticsearch documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-benchmark.html).

```
/bin/elasticsearch --node.bench true

curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_bench/?pretty=true' -d '{
   "name": "my_benchmark",
   "competitors": [ {
       "name": "my_competitor",
       "requests": [ {
        "query": {
            "match": { "_all": "a*" }
                     }
              } ] 
         } ]
}'
```

But I get the exception.

```
{   "error" : "InvalidIndexNameException[[_bench] Invalid index name
[_bench], must not start with '_']",   "status" : 400 }
```

What am I doing wrong.

Comment: are you using any tool for that? You are trying to create and index here with an invalid name. Is there any plugin you are using to benchmark?

Comment: @eliasah I don't use any tools or plugin.

Comment: You'll need a load tester like Tsung or JMeter then!

Comment: @eliasah The documentation does not mention the need. [link](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-benchmark.html)

Comment: I know that it doesn't mention the need, but the benchmark feature is still experimental in Elasticsearch. So I advice you to consider using Tsung or Apache JMeter for that purpose!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the freshly downloaded elasticsearch in version 1.4.2 and I got the same result as you.

Then I compiled elastic search from master branch taken from [github](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch) and it worked. For your curl I got following reply:

```
{
  "status" : "COMPLETE",
  "errors" : [ ],
  "competitors" : {
    "my_competitor" : {
      "summary" : {
        "nodes" : [
        "Cable" ],
        "total_iterations" : 5,
        "completed_iterations" : 5,
        "total_queries" : 5000,
        "concurrency" : 5,
        "multiplier" : 1000,
        "avg_warmup_time" : 0.0,
        "statistics" : {
          "min" : 1,
          "max" : 1,
          "mean" : 1.0,
          "qps" : 1000.0,
          "std_dev" : 0.0,
          "millis_per_hit" : 0.0,
          "percentile_10" : 1.0,
          "percentile_25" : 1.0,
          "percentile_50" : 1.0,
          "percentile_75" : 1.0,
          "percentile_90" : 1.0,
          "percentile_99" : 1.0
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And for simpler curl I got:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_bench?pretty'

{ }
```

So it seems that this functionality is so experimental that it's not yet included in any stable release.

I guess reference [master] in documentation header was not a coincidence ;)